# Is it possible to use NodeJs packages in Angular projects?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package

I would like to use the [Pluralize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pluralize) package in my Angular project but I am not sure if it is possible to use NodeJs packages in Angular.

VS Code throws the error `'Cant find module pluralize'` when i try to import it.

Hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able, just run the command npm install  and it should work.

Sometimes VSCode has bugs and needs a restart. Also, check if you are importing correctly the module

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use npm packages. You can do a (example: file-saver) `npm install file-saver`. Then do a import in ts do:

`import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver'`.

You can now use FileSaver to access the methods/properties of the file-saver package.